# Consistent mysqldump of mixed InnoDB and MyISAM tables from RDS instance

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump, myisam, amazon-rds

I have MySQL db on dedicated server. I would like it to be an external master for an RDS instance. And I want to make backups of RDS. (Currently we have mix of both InnoDB and MyISAM but we are slowly transitioning to full InnoDB).

I did `flush tables with read lock` on our master(on dedicated server) and took a dump. Restored that dump on a RDS instance and configured external master. The RDS replication caught up. I am trying to create second slave in RDS from the first slave we have up to date with master.
This is where I run into trouble. I can not get consistent copy to run replication. I tried doing snapshot and building replication from the restored snapshot - but replication gets errors about duplicate entires and foreign constraints. If I skip some errors - replications runs for few minutes and errors again. The tables in the error are not MyISAM.

I tried doing dump. Tried locking tables. Flushing tables.

Because you can not do `flush tables with read lock` on RDS - I tried doing what is said in this AWS article: (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html).

Because the errors are not connected to MyISAM tables I though it is not a problem, but still tried by:

```
use my_db;
flush tables [list of MyISAM tables];
lock each MyISAM table for read: `lock table <MyISAM table> read`
```

But the problem is still the same.

Database is around 100G so I dump it table by table with shell one liner.

Any ideas what and where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Last month, I answered this question : [Synchronizing a RDS instance with another RDS instance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106458/synchronizing-a-rds-instance-with-another-rds-instance/106461#106461)

From researching and answering that post, I recently learned that you can set read_only off on a MySQL RDS Slave. What can this mean for you ? A very unique opportunity. What opportunity ?

***CONVERT ALL YOUR MyISAM TABLES TO InnoDB !!!***

Once you have made the RDS Slave writable by setting read_only to 0, you can change the storage engine of all the tables in the RDS Slave to InnoDB. Don't worry, it is possible for a Master to have MyISAM tables and the Slave to have InnoDB. I have suggested Master and Slave having different storage engines before ([Can I have an InnoDB master and MyISAM slaves with Full-Text for searching?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22422/can-i-have-an-innodb-master-and-myisam-slaves-with-full-text-for-searching/22425#22425))

Once you have converted all that tables in the RDS Slave to InnoDB, you make read replicas of that new Slave without the MyISAM headaches of backing up data.

NOTE : Here is a sample script to convert all your MyISAM tables to InnoDB

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
CONVERT_SCRIPT=/tmp/ConvertMyISAMToInnoDB.sql
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND"
SQL="${SQL} table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
less ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: Cheers Rolando for a swift answer as always :) I will try converting myisam to innodb's and then will try making second replication of it. The thing I am wondering about is if the errors do not mention any myisam tables - does that mean that the problem still might be myisam tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just want to create a [read replica](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/) clicks away from you?

If not then I guess you need to [restore from a dbsnapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html).

You can:

- stop slave.
- note show slave status.
- create db snapshot.
- start  slave on first slave.
- use dbsnapshot to create new rds instance.
- use co-ordinates to replicate from external master.

Also if not and you're looking to create slave of RDS slave then, there is an old [update blog which says it's possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/08/28/amazon-rds-read-replica-new-features/).

Hope this helps.