# Amazon RDS remove read-only and allow defining table structures

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have set up an Amazon RDS Mysql instance and it is successful.
I am trying to create some tables but I am getting this error:

```
#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I have tried to set global to read-only = 0 but my user does not have privileges.
I have tried googling for a solution to no avail. (I am pretty new to RDS)

**Update**
I do not have a create read replica option on my actions

[image]

Comment: I answered this question back on `Jul 09, 2015`. Read my comment where I mention a blog that shows you how to mess with read_only (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106458/synchronizing-a-rds-instance-with-another-rds-instance/106461#106461)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I cannot create a read replica. See update **

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate -- this looks like Aurora, so let's collect some more info.  Is this the master in a single-member Aurora cluster?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes it is.

Comment: Hmmm.  So, is it *really* in read-only mode, or is this error actually indicating something else? `SELECT @@READ_ONLY;`

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot `@@READ_ONLY ==> 0`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Trying to create a table --> http://pastebin.com/ZHdqJYCh

Comment: Interesting. Take another look at your console. `Failover` should be grayed out on the `Instance Actions` drop-down list out if this is the master of a single-member (one master, zero replicas) Aurora cluster, since that action wouldn't be an option available to you (gray-out is what I see in the console for this option when viewing a single-member cluster's master). It isn't grayed out on your screen shot, which suggests that you have at least 2 members in the cluster and the one you're connected to and trying to execute this query on is in fact a replica (despite `@@read_only` = 0). Confirm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, I ran into this problem on one of my stacks—but not the first time the stack was built. It seems I was referencing an `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`'s `DBInstance.Endpoint.Address`, but that instance was actually the master member of an Aurora RDS database cluster.

For some reason, accessing the instance directly sometimes caused the `--read-only` error. I updated my template to output an `AWS::RDS::DBCluster`'s `DBCluster.Endpoint.Address` instead (so my app would point at the cluster endpoint, and not the instance directly), and everything worked fine.

It was puzzling to me why this happened sometimes when I built a stack and not others... but the lesson is to make sure you use the cluster endpoint if you have a multiple-member Aurora/RDS cluster, and not just a single instance.

Comment: Where i will get the options to change the parameters

Answer (score 3):

This also works for the RDS Blue/Green deployments recently released.

- Create a new parameter group and set `read_only = 0`.
- Set your read replica / green deployment to this parameter group.
- Check that the parameter group has applied, it should apply without the need for rebooting.
- Verify by running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'read_only';`

It should display :

> read_only OFF

Additionally if your purpose of removing the `read_only` is to change column types such as `tiny int` to `int`, you will also need to change the `slave_type_conversions` parameter. I would recommend setting it to `ALL_NON_LOSSY` as the safest option.
See documentation for more details https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-replica.html#sysvar_slave_type_conversions